# How to bring up a wi-fi interface?

Tags: linux, wifi

I can't figure out how to properly bring up the camera’s Wi-Fi. It is a cheap Chinese camera build upon ANAKA 3918 SoC and ssv6x5x Wi-Fi chip.

I am able to load Wi-Fi driver-module, and the driver is instantiated, but any attempt to bring it up fails.

```
echo 1 > /sys/user-gpio/wifi_en         #Enable WiFi device
lsmod                       #show mods status
#   Tainted: G
#   ak_info_dump 1227 0 - Live 0xbf019000
#   akcamera 14136 2 ak_info_dump, Live 0xbf011000
#   sensor_H63 4066 0 - Live 0xbf00d000 (O)
#   sensor_h62 3136 0 - Live 0xbf009000
#   sensor_gc1054 4313 0 - Live 0xbf004000 (O)
#   sensor_gc1034 3813 0 - Live 0xbf000000

Ifconfig                        #show network devices status
#   Lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
#       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
#       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
#       RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
#       TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
#       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
#       RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

insmod /usr/modeules/ssv6x5x.ko     #insert wifi driver
lsmod                       #show mods status, note ss6x5x driver loaded
 #   Tainted: G
#   ssv6x5x 414810 0 - Live 0xbf01d000 (O)
#   ak_info_dump 1227 0 - Live 0xbf019000
#   akcamera 14136 2 ak_info_dump, Live 0xbf011000
#   sensor_H63 4066 0 - Live 0xbf00d000 (O)
#   sensor_h62 3136 0 - Live 0xbf009000
#   sensor_gc1054 4313 0 - Live 0xbf004000 (O)
#   sensor_gc1034 3813 0 - Live 0xbf000000

Ifconfig                        #show network devices status
                        #note: nothing about wlan
#   lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
#       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
#       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
#                RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
#               TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
#               collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
#               RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Ifconfig wlan0 up       #gives error ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

I cannot find any error messages in /var/log/messages, no errors firm insmod etc. Because I am using embedded Linux, the troubleshooting is quite limited. Can you advice what else can be done?

Comment: Ask the vendor however you can. It's highly unlikely anyone here has intimate knowledge of your HW.

Comment: Thanks for your wisdom, I have tried, but nobody responded to my queries from Anyka corp. I found a few posts on China forums but in Chinese for Chines.  They have a very interesting viewpoint on the open-source concept.

Comment: Looks like you are not aware of the requirement to configure the wireless network parameters first. If you are using a modern protected WiFi network (with a WPA or better encryption), you will need `wpa_supplicant` or similar utility to manage the encryption and network association. Since that is essentially the wireless equivalent of *plugging in the network cable*, it needs to be done first before the interface can accept IP address configuration - or any `ifconfig` operations for that matter.